# SolrQuery Return Nothing SolrNet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, solrnet

I'm new to `solr` and `solrNet`, I have a project in which I want to index my files and then search for them, Indexing is working but searching always return nothing.

My code for indexing:

```
 using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
                {
                    var response =
                        solr.Extract(
                            new ExtractParameters(fileStream, "Hello")
                            {
                                ExtractFormat = ExtractFormat.Text,
                                ExtractOnly = false
                            });
                }


                solr.Commit();
```

My code for searching:

```
 var metadata = solr.Query(new SolrQuery ("id:Hello"));
                foreach(var item in metadata)
                MessageBox.Show(item.title);
                ViewData["view"] = metadata;
```

Comment: Try setting a content type. Also check out the Solr logs

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was I didn`t set index = true for the properties. Thanks for ur reply